# Match PHP Comment Constructs with REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regex that matches a single-line php comment starting with a double forward slash and continuing until the end of the line. My regex pattern is supposed to match every character after the double forward slash and the Negative Lookbehind construct limits the match up to every character preceding a new line break.

Currently, the regex pattern only matches single line strings, but fails when the string is broken into multiple line breaks. How may I fix this?

```
$detail = '//This first line is a comment 
This second line is not a comment.';
function parser($detail) 
{
    if (preg_match('#(//.*)((?<!.)\r\n)$#', $detail)) 
    {
        $errors[] = 'Password should include uppercase and lowercase characters.';
        $detail = preg_replace('#(//.*)((?<!.)\r\n)$#','<span class="com"   style="color:red">$1</span>', $detail);
    return $detail;
    }
}
echo parser($detail);
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/

Comment: If you just want to match until the end of a line use `\V*` or `$#m`

Comment: @mario, \V* returns only the march, I need to return the full string with the comment part wrapped in the span class as shown in the code. Any ideas on how to manipulate the regex to return that?

Comment: @PeeHaa, this is a learning exercise, I am not looking for a precooked application.

Comment: You are overthinking this. If you need the full match, use mario's simple regex inside parenthesis and use `preg_match`'s optional third parameter http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @rjdown your recommendation will always return the last line in the string as the comment march. In this instance, it should be the first line with double forward slashes and not the last line as returned by this this                                                                    $detail = preg_replace('#(\V*)$#','<span class="com" style="color:red">$1</span>', $detail);

Comment: The regex should march the comment line  and replace it with the span class in the preg_replace construct. However the whole string must be returned with the comment highlighted.

Comment: see if `\/\/[^\n]*` or `'(\/\/[^']*)'` helps

Comment: I don't believe there is any `//` comment in this `$detail = '//This first line is a comment ... This second line is not a comment.';`

Comment: Otherwise `//.*)((?<!.)\r\n)$#', $detail)) ` is a comment too.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet below answered my question. Match any line of a string beginning with a double forward slash and ends with any character except new line. Isolate the matched line as a token for styling. The function then returns the full string with the comment styled as needed.

```
$detail = '//This line is a comment
This second line is not a comment
This third line is not a comment';
function parser($detail) 
{
    $detail = preg_replace('#//(.*)#','<span style="color:red">//$1</span><br/>', $detail);
    return $detail;
}
echo parser($detail);
```